# Typescript declaration file for a function that returns a merged copy of 2 objects

Tags: javascript, typescript

I have a function that takes 2 objects and returns a copy of both objects merged. I would like to write a declaration file for it but I cannot figure out how to do so.

Ideally I would like to do something like this

```
function deepMerge<T,K>(obj: T, obj2: K): {...T, ...K}
```

But typescript won't let me do that.

Any ideas?

Comment: Like `: T & K`? See https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/unions-and-intersections.html#intersection-types.

Comment: Both these answers are good! For some reason I didn't find anything on this when I was looking. I was obviously looking in the wrong place! Thanks guys!